# Skip after_save callback on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an after_save callback in my model:

```
after_save :do_stuff
```

However I want Rails to ignore it on my model's create action, something like

```
after_save :do_stuff, skip: on_create
```

What's a good way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `except` try these:

```
after_save :do_stuff, except: :create
```

Or

```
use after_update
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `after_update` callback. As the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_update) said:

> Is called after Base.save on existing objects that have a record.

Answer (score 0):

In that case - don't use `after_save` callback.

The purpose of `after_save` is to run every time you SAVE an object, so it will get called when the object is created (-> because it get saved for the first time) and when the object is being updated.

As @JesusTinoco answered, you should use the `after_update` callback which will get called only when you UPDATE the object.

```
after_update :do_stuff
```

(PS: there is also `after_create` callback which will get called only when you CREATE an object.)